# Nokogiri- creating a hash for each scraped result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am attempting to create a hash for each result that matches my css selector. As it stands, there are about 10 results per page, but I would like to create a hash for each of these results. What would be the best way going about this?

Or perhaps it makes sense to limit the number of results found in nokogiri?

```
 listing_data = @nodes




listing = {


    :url => listing_data.css('div#content div.content_inner div.section div.supercolumn div.column div.block div.items div#pages div.unsponsored div.item.compact div.item_inner div.photo a img.tiny').text,
    :price => listing_data.css('div#content div.content_inner div.section div.supercolumn div.column div.block div.items div#pages div.unsponsored div.item.compact div.item_inner div.more h3 span').text
}
end
```

Comment: A hash keyed by what? It's unclear what you're asking. And "limiting the number of results" seems a completely different issue, how is that related to what you're asking?

Comment: I think you're right. Let's say I am looking at an ebay search results page. I would like to make a hash for each individual result that includes price, time remaining, and the url. My issue is that I create the hash, and the css selectors give me all of the search results. I am looking for a way to make a hash for each one of these instead of lumping them all together in one hash. Thanks!

Comment: I still don't understand the issue; Nokogiri gives you an iterator over your selector: create the hash and add it to, say, an array, or collect.

Comment: Sorry, I am not wording myself very well. I have added some code to the original post. But long story short, with that code I am generating some 15 prices, an 15 urls. I was hoping that I could create a hash for each listing so that 1 hash would contain 1 url and 1 price. another hash would contain another url and another price. My issue is I am unfamiliar with the syntax to basically say hey, only pull the first result you find and store it in the hash, instead of store all of the results that fit these css selectors. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So `listing_data.css` returns an Array (or something similar) of results? Rough code sketch here:

```
urls = listing_data.css('selector here')
prices = listing_data.css('another selector')
result = urls.zip(prices).map do |url,price|
  {:url => url, :price => price}
end
```